# Why can eclipse fail to suggest an import for a jar in the build path?

Tags: java, eclipse

Usually when you write something in Eclipse like

```
ArrayList<String> list;
```

Eclipse will underline the `ArrayList` and give you a list of options, including importing `java.util.ArrayList`

However sometimes, Eclipse has no import suggestions, and yet when you add the correct import, for a class in a jar on the build path, Eclipse accepts it, so it could clearly see it. Why is it so?

Comment: it works fine for me. Does the file containing the imported class contain unsaved modifications or errors?

Comment: do you know the shortcut for fixing imports or how to open the suggestion box?

Comment: I see Eclipse's code completion fail in general within lambda bodies.

Comment: The quick fix shortcut is Ctrl+1

Comment: The "organize imports" shortcut is Ctrl-Shift-O, for that matter.

Comment: Please can you describe a specific example we can all test?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's beacause an **`organize imports`** proprety in `save actions` preferences, see the image below it'll show you all you need:

[image]

If you select `Organize imports` Eclipse will automatically import the needed imports when you perform save action,  but it only occurs when there is only one possible import for the written code.

Check  `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions` in your Eclipse.